# Using tikz inside align* environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to TikZ and I am trying to use it inside the `align*` environment.
The approach I am taking works within the `center` environment but not in the `align` environment. There are no errors but the output is not as expected.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{chemformula}  

\makeatletter  
    \newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}  
\makeatother  

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,calc}  

\begin{document}  

Using Center environment;  
\begin{center}  
  \ch{\tikzmark{a} Cu^{2+} + 2 e-} \ch{->}  \ch{\tikzmark{b} Cu} \hspace{2ex}   
        electrons gained by \ch{Cu^{2+}}  
                \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{  
        \draw ($ (a.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $+2$};  
        \draw ($ (b.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $0$};  
     }  
\end{center}  

Using Align environment;  
\begin{align*}  
  \ch{\tikzmark{a} Cu^{2+} + 2 e-} &\ch{->}  \ch{\tikzmark{b} Cu} \qquad  
    \text{electrons gained by \ch{Cu^{2+}}}  
                \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{  
        \draw ($ (a.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {+2};  
        \draw ($ (b.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {0};  
     }  
\end{align*}  

\end{document}
```

P.S. What I am trying to do is to place text which seems to appear on the "top left" side of the atomic symbol in the chemical equation. The placement of this text is supposed to be above the atomic symbol. I am using the package chemformula to write the equations and I want to align a bunch of such equations - hence needing to use align*. So, two things:
(1) write a bunch of aligned chemical equations using chemformula package
(2) use TikZ to place text above certain points along the equation

Comment: `align` (and other of the `amsmath` multi-line display environments) have to treat the entire content of the environment as an argument, and pass over it twice to measure what's set inside.  i wouldn't expect anything as complex as `tikz` to work under those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but why using TikZ in this case? If you want exponents on the right, you can write them as usual:

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,calc}  

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node (#1) {};}  

\begin{document}  

Using Center environment;  
\begin{center}  
  \ch{\tikzmark{a} Cu^{2+} + 2 e-} \ch{->}  \ch{\tikzmark{b} Cu} \hspace{2ex}   
        electrons gained by \ch{Cu^{2+}}  
                \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{  
        \draw ($ (a.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $+2$};  
        \draw ($ (b.north) + (0,0.1) $) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $0$};  
     }  
\end{center}  

Using Align environment;  
\begin{align*}  
  \ch{^{\tiny +2}Cu^{2+} + 2 e-} &\ch{->}  \ch{^{\tiny 0}Cu} \qquad  
    \text{electrons gained by \ch{Cu^{2+}}}  
\end{align*}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: shouldn't the left "scripts" be the same size as the ones on the right?  (i see that you've specified `\tiny`, but it looks odd to me; maybe i'm just not familiar with the notation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah. If you remove the `\tiny`, it will be at the same level as the other exponent. It's actually at the same level even now, but being smaller, it gives the impression it's lower.

Comment: I'd still be curious to understand why the `\tikzmark` didn't seem to work inside the `align*` environment.

Comment: @A.Ellett Didn't read it properly on the phone but align scans twiceand tikzmark requires two runs so probably they are clashing on the aux file

Comment: @Alenanno -- since i remembered seeing this just a couple days ago, i looked up the reference.  in the nist [guide for the use of the international system of units (si)](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) it's very specific about presentation.  see examples on pages 24 and 37.  the pre-superscripts definitely look the same size as ordinary superscripts.